# how to use <Head> with nextJS

Tags: meta, next.js, html-head

I'm having problems getting mobile metatags into a nextJS app.
According to the docs here, this should work
https://nextjs.org/docs#populating-head

But I don't see the title or any of my own meta properties getting rendered.
All I see is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta charSet="utf-8" class="next-head"/>
```

which looks like some type of default.

```
import Link from 'next/link'
import Head from 'next/head'
import Header from '../components/Header'
import BaseLayout from '../components/BaseLayout.js'

const Index = () => (
  <BaseLayout>
    <Head>
      <title>HSK App</title>
      <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width" />
    </Head>
    <Link href='/quizList'>
      <h3>HSK Quiz App!</h3>
    </Link>
  </BaseLayout>
)
export default Index
```

Help appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

NextJS's `<Head>` component seems a bit buggy.

For one thing, two `<Head>` tags set in different components sometimes will interfere with each other in really bizarre ways. For another, sometimes having it in page components works, sometimes it doesn't. And the rules seems perfectly random.

The only thing that consistently worked for me is using `<Head>` in `_document.js`. :/

Comment: Just a note on this that using `<Head>` in `_document.js` isn't supported anymore. There's an explicit warning to avoid it, and you should instead use it in `_app.js` if you need to set global tags.

Comment: maybe use the `key='xyz'` attribute. This force to add the given tag only once in the header.

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce this problem. Maybe a bug was fixed since this question was written, but the [documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/head) does point out they use a `key` attribute to help Next.js keep track of meta tags and eliminate duplicates when they appear in parent and child elements.

> To avoid duplicate tags in your `head` you can use the `key` property,
>   which will make sure the tag is only rendered once, as in the
>   following example:

```
import Head from 'next/head'

function IndexPage() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Head>
        <title>My page title</title>
        <meta property="og:title" content="My page title" key="title" />
      </Head>
      <Head>
        <meta property="og:title" content="My new title" key="title" />
      </Head>
      <p>Hello world!</p>
    </div>
  )
}

export default IndexPage
```