# Can you have multiple, additive 'HEAD' elements in NextJS?

Tags: next.js

I want to be able to have a 'master' `HEAD` element in `_document.js` and for certain pages have an additional `HEAD` element that *adds* to what is in the 'master'.  From https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/head it would seem that this is possible.

However, when searching for the answer in Stack Overflow, I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54856503/how-to-use-head-with-nextjs), which seems to indicate that this can lead to unexpected results.

If I can't have multiple `HEAD` elements, do I need to pass data from the individual page through `getInitialProps`?

Comment: The intention of the library is that it is additive as you suspect. The post to which you link seems rather like superstitious programming; the author offers no concrete evidence, only conjecture, and they clearly don't display an understanding of the behavior they observe either.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can simple import `next/head` into any page/component when you need to do something with it

Example:

```
import Head from 'next/head'

function IndexPage() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Head>
        <title>My page title</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width" />
      </Head>
      <p>Hello world!</p>
    </div>
  )
}

export default IndexPage
```

and also have a default Head within `_document.js`

```
import Document, { Head, Main, NextScript } from 'next/document';

export default class MyDocument extends Document {
  render() {
    return (
      <html lang="en">
        <Head>
          <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
        </Head>
        <body>
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
      </html>
    );
  }
}
```

I am not experiencing any issue so far.

Something to remember though:

*The contents of head get cleared upon unmounting the component, so make sure each page completely defines what it needs in head, without making assumptions about what other pages added.*