# Server side rendering with head

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, server-side-rendering

Is it possible to do server side rendering only to `<head></head>` data? I am trying to use feature like next.js:

```
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  return {
    props: {}, // will be passed to the page component as props
  }
}
```

So, in the express server it will catch the exported function getServerSideProps and set the data in the `<head>` tag. I don't want every other features of next.js and thus I don't want to use next.js. Is it even possible?

Comment: can you please further explain, what exactly you want to do....!

Answer (score 1):

In order to server-side render react app without using any SSR framework (next.js,remix.run etc), you have to change the architecture of your app. Because in a single-page application (SPA), browser downloads the empty HTML, parses it and when sees the script, it makes another request to download the bundled javascript code.

To create a function like `getServerSideProps` you have to write a logic to tell your app that before you serve any page, make sure if there is a specific named function (you define it) run this function first. For this, you need to configure your react router differently. Configuration of  [react-router-route-config](https://ui.dev/react-router-route-config).  you could also use different npm packages but finding good documentation would be hard

To learn more about how server-side react app is implemented please read this in-depth article  [react-router-server-rendering](https://ui.dev/react-router-server-rendering).

- You said you do not want to use Next.js but after reading those two articles, you will understand why server-side react frameworks are so popular.

after this, I will quote from the article above to show you how to render only the `head`

```
import Home from "./Home";
import Grid from "./Grid";
import { fetchPopularRepos } from "./api";

    const routes = [
      {
        path: "/",
        component: Home,
      },
      {
        path: "/popular/:id",
        component: Grid,
        // this is like getServerSideprops function. 
        // whatever logic is
        fetchInitialDataCustomFunction: (path = "") => fetchPopularRepos(path.split("/").pop()),
      },
    ];
    
    export default routes;
```

server/index.js

```
import { matchPath } from "react-router-dom"
import routes from '../shared/routes'

app.get("*", (req, res, next) => {
  const activeRoute = routes.find((route) =>
    matchPath(route.path, req.url)
  ) || {}

})
```

> Now, activeRoute will be the route of whatever page the user was
> requesting (req.url).
>
> The next step is to see if that route requires any data. We'll check
> if the activeRoute has a fetchInitialData property. If it does, we'll
> invoke it passing it the current path, if it doesn't, we'll just
> continue on.

Now this is the part where you will implement to send only `head`

```
app.get("*", (req, res, next) => {
  const activeRoute =
    routes.find((route) => matchPath(route.path, req.url)) || {};

  const promise = activeRoute.fetchInitialData
    ? activeRoute.fetchInitialData(req.path)
    : Promise.resolve();

  promise
    .then((data) => {
      const markup = ReactDOM.renderToString(<App serverData={data} />);

      res.send(`
      <!DOCTYPE html>
      <html>
        // this is the head part that you want to implement
        <head>
          <title>SSR with React Router</title>
          <script src="/bundle.js" defer></script>
          <link href="/main.css" rel="stylesheet">

          ------------------------------------------------
          // this part is usually used for redux.
          // we send the data store to the client, so the client will use it as the initial state of the app
          <script>
            window.__INITIAL_DATA__ = ${serialize(data)}
          </script>
        </head>

        // you do not want this part. this is the main content is sent to the client
        <body>
          <div id="app">${markup}</div>
        </body>
      </html>
    `);
    })
    .catch(next);
});
```

Comment: What is App here in `ReactDOM.renderToString(<App serverData={data} />)` ? And doesn't it render all app from server side?

Answer (score 0):

next.js will indeed let you do that with the pre-rendering.

On every page, you can return only the `<head/>` without `<body/>` if you want, as shown here https://stackoverflow.com/a/60398652/18364469

As rendering may be quite complex, If you want a production ready solution, I suggest you to use next.js, they have tackled many issues you may not be aware of. If you don't want to use it, what are your constraints ?

If you're just curious and want to re-create something similar to next.js, I suggest you reading the code on next.js, maybe starting from this file https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/packages/next/server/next-server.ts as you're interested in server developement.

You can also setup a simple express server that returns an html document only with a `<head/>` tag like this.

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('<html><head></head></html>')
})

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`App listening on port ${port}`)
})
```

Feel free to provide more context to get a more accurate answer

Answer (score -1):

Something you could try is using a library like `cheerio` or a headless browser like `Puppeteer` to parse the HTML and extract only the head element. Below is an example using `cheerio`:

```
import cheerio from 'cheerio';

export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  // Load the page HTML
  const res = await fetch(`http://localhost:${process.env.PORT}${context.pathname}`);
  const html = await res.text();

  // Use cheerio to parse the HTML and extract the head element
  const $ = cheerio.load(html);
  const headHtml = $('head').html();

  return {
    props: {
      headHtml,
    },
  };
}
```

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you were looking for, but if so I hope it helps.

Comment: Sorry, this is not what I am looking for. Please re-read my question, hope you understand.

Comment: @EvanOttinger OP wants to set the head tag not want to scrap it!

Comment: I didn't say anything about "scrapping" the head tag. @Zain_Ul_Din