# Difference between <Head> and <head> in Next.js?

Tags: javascript, next.js

I have been learning *Next.js* and I came across with the concept Head, I got confused with head and head(in HTML). I wasn't able to find some good explanations for them. It would be great help if someone could answer them .

Comment: Does this [how to use <Head> with nextJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54856503/how-to-use-head-with-nextjs) answer your question?

Comment: Yep! thanks so much.